# Can't work out "deviceinfoendpoint" imports

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been following these instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities

but I can't work out these imports:

```
import com.testproject.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint;
import com.testproject.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint.Builder;
import com.testproject.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo;
```

Those give errors in Eclipse. Where are they? Why don't they appear in my project? Are they supposed to be generated when I follow the setup instructions on that website I linked?

"testproject" is the name of my project in this case.

If someone could please enlighten me on what's going on here I'll be very grateful. I've been trying to work this out for a couple of days now and it's driving me nuts.

Thanks,
Jarom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a Cloud Endpoint client Library for the App Engine project by right-clicking the App Engine project, and selecting Google > Generate Cloud Endpoint Client  ... then it works

You must repeat this every time you add new Endpoints or modify the fields or methods of an existing one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I eventually got onto someone from Google and got it sorted out. Apparently "Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library" wasn't working in my case (I was actually doing it).